# Can't create table `travel`.`city` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql

I have:

```
CREATE TABLE place(
  placeid int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  placename varchar(255),
  placeinfo text,
  locationx double,
  locationy double
);
```

and create TABLE place is ok, but then I created:

```
CREATE TABLE city(
  cityid int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  placeid int,
  cityname varchar(255),
  image text,
  constraint n foreign key(placeid) references place(placeid) 
);
```

I get an error:

```
Can't create table `travel`.`city` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your placeid column within CITY table is not an UNSIGNED INT as it is in PLACE table.

```
CREATE TABLE city(
   cityid int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   placeid int UNSIGNED,
   cityname varchar(255),
   image text,
   constraint n foreign key(placeid) references place(placeid) 
)
```